# Loading System.Windows.Controls.Image to WritableBitmap object

Tags: c#, wpf, writeablebitmap

I've created Image object in xaml code:

```
<Image Name="Square" Source="Square.png" Height="400" Width="640"/>
```

In code-behind I've written:

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)Square.Width, (int)Square.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);
```

If I'm creating pixel array, puting to WritableBitmap and then to Image like this:

```
    int width = 300;
    int height = 300;
    WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);
    uint[] pixels = new uint[width * height];

    bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, 300, 300), pixels, width * 4, 0);
    **Square.Source = bitmap;**
```

I haven't any problem, but when I'm trying to load my image created in xaml code to WritableBitmap, I can't do this:

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)Square.Width, (int)Square.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);
bitmap = Square.Source; // Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' to 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap'
```

So if I can't convert type *'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'* to *'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap'*, why I can convert *'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap'* to *'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'*?

```
    Square.Source = bitmap;
    bitmap = Square.Source; // Why it does not work?
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried something like this?: `WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(Square.Source);`

Comment: Hi Sheridan, I've put your code in visual but I have to errors:
*The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap.WriteableBitmap(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource)' has some invalid arguments*
**and**
*Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' to 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource'*

Comment: Ahh sorry, I forgot to cast the `ImageSource` to a `BitmapSource`. See @Clemens' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly create a `WriteableBitmap` from any `ImageSource`, because the `ImageSource` might not be a `BitmapSource` (which is what the Writeablebitmap constructor takes as argument).

However, in your case it is safe to cast the `Source` property to `BitmapSource`:

```
var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)Square.Source);
```

---

Note that the `Source` property of Image control is of type `ImageSource` (and not `BitmapSource`) because the control is able to display other types of images than only bitmaps, e.g. vector images.